# Printing an output using pandas .groupby to include keys that equalled to 0?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get an output that includes every key, even if the is an equivalent value of 0.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('climate_data_Dec2017.csv')

wind_direction = df['Direction of maximum wind gust']
is_on_a_specific_day = df['Date'].str.contains("12-26")
specific_day = df[is_on_a_specific_day]

grouped_by_date = specific_day.groupby('Direction of maximum wind gust')
number_record_by_date = grouped_by_date.size()

print(number_record_by_date)
```

The current output looks like this right now:

```
E      4
ENE    2
ESE    1
NE     1
NNE    1
NNW    1
SE     3
SSE    3
SW     1
```

But I'm trying to get it to include other directions too. ie

```
E      4
ENE    2
ESE    1
N      0
NE     1
NNE    1
NNW    1
NW     0
S      0
SE     3
SSE    3
SW     1
...
```

Is there any way to get my code to include it? I tried to group it by the wind direction dataframe rather than the specific_day dataframe, but going down that route, I'm stuck on what to do next. Any pointers would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need something like this:

```
df['is_on_a_specific_day'] = df['Date'].str.contains("12-26")
df.groupy('Direction of maximum wind gust').sum()[['is_on_a_specific_day']]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

- Computing a list with all the unique value of the column 'Direction of maximum wind gust' in the original dataset (`list_all_dirs = df['Direction of maximum wind gust'].unique()`)
- Filter the dataset and compute the groupby as you said
- Append to the result one row for each of the value in the list that is not already there. What you can do is building a series like this:
  `series_to_append = pd.Series({dir: 0 for dir in list_all_dirs if dir not in number_record_by_date.index}, name='Direction of maximum wind gust')` and then append it to the series you already computed at the previous step.

Eleonora